# How to get notified of a QComboBox index change inside a QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt

**Scenerio:**
I have a 2 column QTreeWidget in my MainWindow. I add a row with text in the first column and a QComboBox in the second using the following code:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *rowItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(mainTree);
QComboBox *comboBox = GenerateComboBox(mainTree);
comboBox->setCurrentIndex(someIndexValue);
rowItem->setText(0,someText);
mainTree->setItemWidget(rowItem,1,comboBox);
```

My intention is to have a slot that does some work when the index of a combobox has changed.  I need to know the row number of the TreeItem the changed comboBox resides in, in-addition to the index of the comboBox that value has changed to.

---

***Current Understanding:***
With my limited knowledge of QT:
 1. It doesn't seem the TreeItem and comboBox are aware of each other as the TreeWidget is used as the parent for both.
 2. I don't see a way to connect comboBox's indexChanged signal to a TreeItem itemChanged slot using what's already there to propagate the change notification up.

---

***Question:***
Is there a way to achieve this without writing a wrapper class that implements a slots and signal with the needed parameters or adding that implementation to the QTreeItem/QComboBox classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda function:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);


    QTreeWidget * mainTree = new QTreeWidget;
    mainTree->setColumnCount(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        QTreeWidgetItem *rowItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(mainTree);
        rowItem->setText(0, QString("item %1").arg(i));
        QComboBox * comboBox = new QComboBox();
        comboBox->addItems({"option1", "option2", "option3", "option4"});
        mainTree->setItemWidget(rowItem, 1, comboBox);

        QObject::connect(comboBox, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), comboBox,
            [comboBox, rowItem](int index){
            qDebug() << index << comboBox << rowItem->text(0);
        });
    }

    QMainWindow w;
    w.setCentralWidget(mainTree);   
    w.resize(640, 480);
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a question about the lambda function: When I'm trying to use it to call upon a slot in another class the compiler says `this was not captured for this lambda function` and if I try to include the function it says `capture of non-variable`. I'm trying to pass the row and index value to a slot function in the MainWindow class so it modifies data it has access to. I don't want to have the comboBox to have access to the data I'm trying to modify. The body of my lambda looks like this: `emit MainWindow::on_event(row,index);`

Comment: @Petro try changing `[comboBox, rowItem]` to  `[&]`

Comment: changing to & fixes the compiler from complaining, but when I access the comboBox and WidgetItem, I get garbage values.

Comment: @Petro I think that you have incorrectly implemented my solution. 1) Have you tested my code? Has my project worked for you? 2) If the above is affirmative then I am correct: you have not correctly implemented my solution, so if you want more help edit your question adding how you have implemented my solution in your case to see where the problem is.